# Services of differnt name having 2 exe

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have 2 exe files named  as  ActiveGateway.exe and ActiveLBS.exe which is running on window service ACTIVEServer and i copied that service and change its name as ActiveServer1 and 2 exe as Gateway.exe and LBS.exe.and change the installation path .after this if we trying to insatl this service it shows an error.this version already exist.i changed the version number product name and all..but still issue is like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that needs to be done is to make sure that the name of each service installation instance is unique. Then you need to have copies of installation directories for each service instance you'd like to have. Finally, you need to be able to set the service name dynamically during installation and startup. This will be facilitated using the app.config file.

The cleanest and most readily available way of providing the service name is to use an app.config file for your service and create an appSettings key that can be read from to set the service name. An app.config file needs to be added to your solution if one doesn't already exist to store the unique service name in order to dynamically set the ServiceInstaller.ServiceName and the ServiceBase.ServiceName to the same service name value you added to your configuration.

Source: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21320/Multiple-Instance-NET-Windows-Service

Comment: Error like 'unable to install because a newver version of this product already insatlled '  kinldy give  a solution for thsi